# XAML: namespace strange behaviour Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, xml-namespaces

I have a problem with one of my current WPF projects. The project used to compile (and run) just fine. Then we decided to remove the Extended WPF Toolkit from the librarys because of licensing concerns. I had used the `NumericUpDown`s (`ShortUpDown`, ... not the deprecated one) so I decided I should write my own.

I have written a `UserControl` and am quite happy with this but as soon as I exchanged the UpDowns with my control which I called `MySpinner` it stopped working:

- The designer doesnt display my window anymore with the error message: *"The Design view cannot display correctly because some custom elements have not yet been built."*.
- My project **doesnt** build anymore with lots of error messages stating that all my used classes are not located in their namespace (every class except `MySpinner`) or (errors from code behind) stating that my named controls (of type `MySpinner`) dont exist in the current context - probably due to the XAML not compiling.

Everything in my project is in the namespace `DeviceSimulator` which I have "imported" as `con` with the line: `xmlns:con="clr-namespace:DeviceSimulator"` in the start of my `Window` (which worked perfectly before).

If I type `<con:` IntelliSense even correctly presents me with every class in the namespace as a possible completion.

I know there are a lot of questions already with seemingly similar topics but the difference is that in my case the project **does not** build. The issue that the project builds despite the errors is something I have run across a few times but this is not the case here.

I tried the solutions proposed on the other questions like restarting, rebuilding, cleaning or changing the compile target from `Any CPU` to `x86` and back but nothing worked (building and rebuilding dont work because the solution doesnt compile). Everything I am using resides locally in my project folder (except of course the default namespace definitions from `schemas.microsoft.com...`), there are no extra libraries or such that I include and I am not working on a network or server of any kind.

The problem occurs in Visual Studio 2013 as well as 2012 of which I use the Express versions.

Comment: Try removing the broken lines. Rebuilding and then reinserting the lines.

Comment: @Gusdor You mean remove every line that references a named Control in code behind and every line that uses something from the namespace in XAML? There wouldnt be much left

Comment: If I recall correctly, the bogus errors that the XAML designer routinely generates can *sometimes* cause VS to actually refuse to build. I always leave it disabled nowadays. It's a long shot, but have you tried building from a fresh Visual Studio instance with none of your XAML files opened?

Comment: @nmclean I have not tried that but I will try that after I have commented out everything as Gusdor suggested

Comment: @Gusdor After commenting and uncommenting nearly everything in my project it now compiles again. If you would post it as an answer I will accept it so that people see that this was actually solved.

Comment: @nmclean Gusdors suggestionen fixed the error but thank you anyway for your help. And out of curiosity what do you disable? The designer?

Comment: @mgttlinger Yes, I disable the designer. Right-click a XAML file, select "Open With", choose "Source Code (Text) Editor" and "Set as Default". It gives you the full features of the XAML code editor but without the designer (the designer can still be accessed on demand from the View menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gusdor suggested in the comments the problem got fixed by removing every single broken line from the projekt and rebuilding it.

So it seems the problem was some sort of circular dependency in the project (UserControl > XAML > UserControl) which got fixed by breaking the dependency then building one part so that afterwards the dependency could be reinserted and the project could be compiled as a whole.

*I posted this answer as Gusdor didn't seem to post his answer and I didn't want this question to seem unanswered.*

Comment: you may not know it, but you saved my life with this. I was going crazy with a totally unreasonable error that just appeared when compiling (before was working fine) and i couldn't fix.. until i read your first sentence. Thank you, really, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> As the user has already found a solution to their problem, this is not meant to be an answer, rather just some information relating to this situation.

When you find yourself with dozens or even hundreds of errors in a solution that previously had none, you can rest assured that they are mostly 'red herrings', or false/temporary errors. This happens because something was recently changed and caused one, or maybe a few errors in a project.

Often, other projects have references to the now broken project and so any classes that reference classes from the broken project now also show one or more errors... these are the false, or more accurately, temporary errors, which will disappear when the actual error is fixed and that project builds again.

This can also occur in a single project application when an error in one class will cause other classes that reference the broken class to display errors saying that a certain class does not exist when it clearly does. This is a bit like when you change the solution platform or solution configuration, except that in that case, Visual Studio will realise that those errors are not actual errors itself.

So how do we fix these problems? In general, it is quite easy because it was normally the last thing that was edited that is causing the actual error. Even if this is not the case, you can look at the `Project` column of the `Error List` in Visual Studio, and usually the project name that appears the most is the one with the error.

Furthermore, you can ignore a lot of the errors that say something like 'Class X cannot be found in Project/Namespace Y' because you know that they do. Tracking down the actual error is the trickiest part.

One more tip that can help for multi project applications is to use the `Build > Build XXX (ProjectName)` option instead of the `Build Solution` option to build the broken project first. You'll need to select the relevant project in the `Solution Explorer` first. Sometimes projects just need to be built in a certain order, but using the `Build Solution` option has its own build order which might be different.

The error that the question author initially had in the designer sounds like all they actually needed to do was to build the project containing the `CustomControls` first and then to build the remaining projects when that project had a dll file.

I hope that helps other users facing hundreds of errors.

Comment: Just a bit of clarification regarding my project. There was and is only one project; the user control was in the same project as the UI using it so building only the control was no option. But your recommendations may help others stumbling across this thread nontheless.

Comment: Found also that when a lot of errors pop-up after a change that aren't directly related to the change, it can often be because the compiler just hasn't gotten to that part of the project, yet. **Example:**  We got an error to fix the namespace on the Startup project in the Project properties because we had changed it in our project. It still *also* gave errors that the namespace couldn't be found in places we had already updated it, but this was because the project couldn't get to the startup app. **Moral:**  Start with the biggest errors affecting the startup behavior first, and work forward.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see XAML code in the XAML Designer, the page definitely has to be proper markup.  The code-behind that doesn't compile should be commented out, so you can build your project.

Had a similar problem in our project when we were trying to migrate a class called "BaseView" and a XAML page from its old project into our new one.  The projects had different namespaces.  The XAML page we were moving inherited the `BaseView` class in its code-behind, instead of `Page`.

1. We did an "Add Existing Project" within the Solution Explorer, then did a drag-and-drop copy of the class and the page (which brought over its code-behind file) from the old project to the new, all from within the new project's Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.  (**Note:** We later found we should have created a new folder in our new project, not dragged the folder containing code from the old project the new, and just done a copy of the old code and pasted it in the new folder) (Details on how we got to this point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879x19d1(v=vs.90).aspx)
2. We updated the namespace and `using` statements that referenced the old namespace in the `BaseView` class file and XAML page code-behind.
3. We updated the namespace in the XAML page directive, which was inheriting from our class file:  `<v:BaseView x:Class="OurNamespace.View.PageClassName" ...` down to `vmlns:v="clr-namespace:OurNamespace.View"...`.

Even after a "Build Solution", we found it gave the dreaded "*The Design view cannot display correctly because some custom elements have not yet been built*" error. We were getting errors when hovering over `<v:BaseView` in our XAML markup that `BaseView` did not reside in `OurNamespace`, even though `BaseView` had its namespace updated correctly.

To resolve the error, between moving the class file to the root (out of the folder where the XAML page lived), doing a "Build Solution", then moving it back to the folder, doing another "Build Solution", and then clicking a button called "**Enable project code**" that is at the bottom of the XAML Designer,  just to the left of the horizontal scrollbar, we finally got it to recognize the class and finally the XAML Designer came to life - whether it was the button or that second build, not sure which solved it - probably the button if I had to put money on it.

Later we found that we still had the issue if we launched the project from another workstation, and it would give this error in the Output tab if we tried to open a XAML page:

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache\4olitigs.k2m\hj4ewy5v.g23\MyApplication.dll

Could not load file or assembly 'MyApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. This assembly was compiled for a different processor.
```

While it was fine on the original workstation, it failed on a second one.  Turns out it was the **Platform target** in the **Build** tab of the Project Properties.  It needs to be set to "Any CPU" - at least in our case - to avoid the differences between the machines.

Comment: After looking at all other possible solutions, changing it to Any CPU from our previous option of x64 fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, the solution for me was that I didn't add ";assembly=MyAssembly" at the end of the xmlns CLR namespace definition.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this for me was adding the following lines to the project file `.csproj`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>AssemblyName</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>AssemblyName</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```